# Domain PC Logon Server not correct

Tags: domain-name-system, authentication

my production environment I have one parent domain controller three additional domain controllers (ad.domain.com, bjpdc.domain.com, dlpdc.domain.com) and multiple child domain controllers (ad.bj.domain.com, ad.cc.domain.com, ad.dl.domain.com etc.), different area computers join in local domain(BJPC join in bj.domain.com, DLPC join in dl.domain.com).

Also, I put same area domain controllers in one sites (DL Site including dlpdc.domain.com and ad.dl.domain.com, BJ site including bjpdc.domain.com and ad.bj.domain.com). Here is my issue. When I logon child domain’s PC with parent’s account. I found the logon server is not correct(echo %logonserver%).

In my view, when I logon BJPC (In BJ site) with parent’s account it should be use bjpdc.domain.com domain controller to verify my account and password, but now it is random(some BJPC use ad.domain.com some PC use dlpdc.domain.com). It’s so weird. How can I change it ? Thanks

Comment: And you are sure you have set your sites / subnets correctly?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is correctly.